# Is it possible to create relational metabox values in a custom post?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, customization

I have a custom post type (`'Model'`) for a sports modelling agency, and it requires the model to enter sports they are competent at, and also rank their ability from 1 to 5. For example, given the information:

`Model: Joe Soap.

Football: 4.

Archery: 2`

I would store this in the custom_post_type `'model'` with the fields:

`Model Name: Joe Soap.

 Sports: Football, Archery (taxonomy).

 Rank: 4, 2.`

How do I associate `4` with `Football` and `2` with `Archery` using a metabox, where different models may have different sports in their lists ?

Comment: hm... I misunderstood your initial question. Store "rank" as a multidimensional array (into a option), like `$rank[sports_taxonomy_term][rank_value]`

Comment: That sounds like what I need - can you be more specific, or point me to a tutorial/documentation on how to do that within a custom post?

Comment: first, create your rank metabox (the form that gets the values) and post the code here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is focusing on the wrong thing. A metabox is just one way for a user to introduce some data. The more important question is how you should store that data in the database.

You could make 'sport' a custom post type and connect it to models using the [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin. Then, for each connection, you can associate a 'rank' custom field:

https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Connection-information

The plugin takes care of creating a metabox and of storing the values in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

[`add_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) documentation in Codex has example of metabox creation and links to related tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial on adding custom meta boxes is also really good: http://webdesignfan.com/custom-write-panels-in-wordpress/

It's all very flexible; you should be able to reuse the code you create.